# Xcode / Swift: UITextView font changing when setting text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitextview, uifont

I am making an app which requires saving text from one `UITextView`and then viewing it in another one. I am using the font `Bodoni 72 Oldstyle Book` (set with Storyboard), but the second `UITextView` (where the text is displayed) switches to Helvetica when the text is loaded (with `myTextView.text = "the text that was saved"`).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard? Remember you need to specify the font of UITextView either in the Storyboard interface or via code,

Comment: Yes, I am using Storyboard, which is where I set the font for the UITextView.

Comment: I found a workaround: I made a (hidden) label with the desired font, and set the `UITextView`'s font to the label's font.